# AS3 - Check if a shape is closed

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, drawing, shapes, fill

Using 'lineTo()' to draw a shape, I need to check if the drawn line creates a closed shape.
If so I need to fill that shape with a colour.
Could someone please let me know if this is possible, and if so how to do it please.
Thanks

Comment: You can obviously just check if the last point is the same as the first, but it sounds like your requirements are more complicated. Do you need to fill the parts of a line that loops back on itself, like the loop in "e" for example?

Comment: Thanks for replying David, But yes it is more complicated.
It is exactly that, filling in the top looped part of the e.

Answer (score 0):

Before using lineTo, call beginFill. Something like this:

```
var _s:Sprite = new Sprite();
_s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
_s.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFF00);
_s.graphics.lineTo(50, 0);
_s.graphics.lineTo(50, 50);
_s.graphics.lineTo(0, 50);
_s.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);
_s.graphics.endFill();
addChild(_s);
```

P.S. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: Just wondering, would this work if the shape didn't close at the point it started at? For example, if the last line crossed halfway through the first?

Comment: Thanks Rizzla,
Although, wouldn't that fill every time?
If I draw a curved line I wouldn't want to fill, I only want to fill if the line closes the shape.

Comment: @puggsoy yes it will work, but you'll get unpredictable results.

Comment: @atomicDroid call endFill() before drawing if you don't want to fill the next shape.

Comment: The reason is, the line is drawn with the mouse.
I can't decide whether to fill the shape (If it is a shape and not a line) until after the mouse is lifted.

Comment: @atomicDroid You can "cheat" a little. Store the starting point, find out the last point, then calculate the distance between those 2 points - if the distance is less than, say 5px, then it's a closed shape and you can fill it, if not, don't filled it.

Comment: @atomicDroid I reread your question again, sorry. As I said in previous comment, that's the way to find out if it's closed shape. Now, I assume that the drawing is real time? Than, store all the points as the user draws, when he is finished, find out if it's the shape closed, and if it is, than clear all the graphic, redraw again from the stored points and enable fill.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution is probably to store the path as a list of points as it's being drawn, then check each new segment against the existing ones for an intersection. Whenever you find one, draw a separate loop for the fill in this order:

- Intersection.
- Second vertex of existing segment.
- All intermediate vertices up to and including the first vertex of new segment.
- Intersection.

One potential problem with that is that if you draw a few small loops, then circle around them, you'd end up with a large fill intersecting itself and overlapping the small loops, which might render poorly along the edges.

Ideally, you'd want to create a graph of the path with any intersections added, then find every cycle which isn't contained within another cycle, but that's obviously a bit more involved. This previous question has some answers related to finding all the loops which *don't* contain other loops, which could be adapted by combining cycles that share edges: **[Find all chordless cycles in an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022662/find-all-chordless-cycles-in-an-undirected-graph)**.