# Find cycles in a graph that don't contain smaller cycle within it

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, computer-science

Given the edges of a graph, I wish to create an algorithm in python to find all cycles where there are no other cycles within it, I have tried various ideas for several days with no 100% reliability.

For example,

[image]

This graph has the edges as follow:

```
[[0,1],[2,1],[0,2],[0,3],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

And there are 7 possible distinct cycles/loops:

```
[[0, 2, 1, 0], [0, 3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 3, 1, 0], [0, 2, 3, 1, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 2, 0], [1, 3, 2, 1]]
```

But the cycle `[0,3,2,1,0]` has the cycle `[0,2,1,0]` and `[0,3,2,0]` embedded within it. Similarly `[0,2,3,1,0]` has the cycles `[0,3,2,0]` and `[0,3,1,0]` embedded within it. Same goes for `[0,3,1,2,0]` and `[1,3,2,1]`.

Therefore, my python program should filter all that out and give

```
[[0,2,1,0],[0,3,1,0],[0,3,2,0]]
```

which are cycles with no other cycles within it.

Comment: I've tried that but if I do that [0,3,2,0] also gets filtered out because all nodes have been visited in the cycles [0,2,1,0],[0,3,1,0]

Comment: See also: [Algorithm for finding minimal cycles in a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782898/algorithm-for-finding-minimal-cycles-in-a-graph).

Answer (score 1):

You've identified all cycles.  For determining minimal cycles, the node order is immaterial: a minimal cycle is uniquely identified by its *set* of nodes.

Convert each list of nodes to a set.  Make a new list of sets that have no subsets in the list.

```
cycle_list = [
    [0, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 3, 2, 1, 0],
    [0, 3, 1, 0],
    [0, 2, 3, 1, 0],
    [0, 3, 1, 2, 0],
    [0, 3, 2, 0],
    [1, 3, 2, 1]
]

set_list = [set(c) for c in cycle_list]
min_cycle = [c for c in set_list if c!= super
             and not any(super < c for super in set_list)
             ]
print(min_cycle)
```

Output:

```
[{0, 1, 2}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

If you want the cycles in node order, I trust that you can map the four solutions (1, 2, 3, 1 is also a solution) back to the original list.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq those nodes are connected in that order.  Where are you confused?  It's even listed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This method solves a *slightly* different problem, but perhaps you can adapt it to your particular case. I'll fix the answer at some point in the future.

---

This method runs `dfs()` to list all candidate cycles from a particular `start` node. `was_traversed()` is used to check if a particular path was already traversed in the current path. Then, the "duplicate" cycles are trimmed away in the `cycles()` method.

```
def cycles(graph, start):
    paths = {tuple(sorted(xs)): xs for xs in dfs(graph, [start])}
    return paths.values()

def dfs(graph, path):
    for node in graph[path[-1]]:
        if was_traversed(path, path[-1], node):
            continue
        if node == path[0]:
            yield path + [node]
            continue
        yield from dfs(graph, path + [node])

def was_traversed(path, a, b):
    query = sorted([a, b])
    return any(
        sorted([x, y]) == query
        for x, y in zip(path[:-1], path[1:])
    )
```

---

**Test:**

```
>>> graph = {
...     0: [1, 2, 3],
...     1: [0, 2, 3],
...     2: [0, 1, 3],
...     3: [0, 1, 2],
... }

>>> for cycle in dfs(graph, [0]):
...     print(cycle)
[0, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 0]
[0, 1, 3, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 2, 1, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 3, 0]
[0, 2, 3, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 1, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 2, 0]
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0]

>>> for cycle in cycles(graph, 0):
...     print(cycle)
[0, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 1, 0]
[0, 3, 2, 0]
```

Comment: You omitted the edge (2, 1); check the original post.