# Cycles in an undirected graph in R

Tags: r, graph-theory, cycle

I have an undirected graph and what I would like to do is detect cycles that have three or more nodes in them.  Is there a library in R that would do this?  If not is there a simple algorithm that I could implement.

```
test <- data.frame(start=c(1,2,3,4), stop=c(2,3,1,5))
```

I would like it to come back with 1,2,3 and any other cycles it finds.

Comment: Does it have to be `R`? Added a python solution to my answer.

Comment: I'd prefer R as that is what I am use to, but have done a few bits in python before so I am happy to give it a go.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, this won't give you the actual nodes in your cycles, but it will count the cycles of each rank in your graph, so it's a start.

```
library(igraph)
test <- data.frame(start=c(1,2,3,4), stop=c(2,3,1,5))
g <- graph.data.frame(test)

cycles <- t(sapply(3:dim(test)[1], function(x) {v=graph.motifs.no(g, size=x); c(x,v)}))
colnames(cycles) <- c("size","count")

     size count
[1,]    3     1
[2,]    4     0
```

I recommend you play around with the `igraph` library anyway: I couldn't find a solution for you in there, but I suspect that's where you'll find your answer. `graph.motifs` looks promising, but I wasn't able to interpret the result.

If it doesn't have to be `R`, the `networkx` library in python has a [simple_cycles()](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.cycles.html) function that should be sufficient for your needs.

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.cycles import simple_cycles
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
g.add_edge(2,3)
g.add_edge(3,4)
g.add_edge(3,1)
g.add_edge(4,1)
simple_cycles(g)

# [[1,2,3,1],[1,2,3,4,1]]
```

Comment: The only problem I can see with simple_cycles is that it is for directed graphs.  My dataset is undirected, it is possible it might still work through.

Comment: Oh right, undirected. `simple_cycles()` only works for directed. Here are two SO discussions you may find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4028855/819544 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/526371/819544. Looks like you can be clever with a DFS and that might be enough.