# How to detect all regions that are surrounded by n line segments?

Tags: math, geometry, triangular

When you draw 3 line segments in a 2-dimensional plane, it might compose a triangle.

How can I find all polygons that are produced by n line segments? Are there any efficient algorithms I can use?

Input: first and last point coordinate for each line segments (Ex. Points A=(x_A,y_A), B=(x_B,y_B), ... , I=(x_I,y_I))

[image: lines]

Output: All produced polygons and producing line sets (Ex. {A,B,C,F},{A,C,E,F,H},{E,F,I},{E,F,I,H},{G,H,I})

[image: polygons produced by given lines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

**Step 1. Calculate all intersecting points for each line segments.**

Referring "[How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)", calculate all intersecting points for the given line segments. It's O(n^2), but can be upgraded to O(n log n) by using spatial trees (ex. R-Tree, Quad trees).

[image]

**Step 2. Find all couter-clockwise loops.**

Referring "[small cycle finding in a planar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838076/small-cycle-finding-in-a-planar-graph)", Calculate the connecting edge angle for each vertex, and sort it. After it's done, traverse every edges and find all loops by "turning to the most-left-edge" strategy.

This will find all loops, but will also find an outer loop that's not needed. The outer loop is clockwise, compared to other loops that are all counter-clockwise, so remove the clockwise loop by using method written in "[How to determine if a list of polygon points are in clockwise order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165647/how-to-determine-if-a-list-of-polygon-points-are-in-clockwise-order)".

[image]