# NetworkX cycle_basis returns non-basis cycles?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

For a [discrete element modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method) project I have recently started looking into the graph representation of a collection of particles in contact. The basic idea is this: I have a granular aggregate consisting of a number of particles. Each particle interacts with its neighbours through contact points, which can be represented as edges connecting the particles (nodes). The objective is then to extract the [cycle basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis), i.e. the set of smallest possible cycles from which larger cycles can be constructed. To this end, I construct a graph using the Python `networkx` package, and then extract the cycle basis using the [`networkx.cycle_basis`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.cycle_basis) function. A simple example pseudo-code to illustrate my procedure:

```
import networkx as nx

nodes = [particle IDs]
edges = [pairs of particle IDs]
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)
cycles = nx.cycle_basis(G)
```

`cycles` represents a list of lists of the particle IDs participating in each basis cycle. However, when I plot the graph (using the coordinates of the particles in the simulation), I see that `cycles` contains a number of cycles that are actually a combination of smaller cycles, and are therefore not basis cycles (if I understood correctly). An example is shown below:

[image]

Here, the black lines connecting the particles represent the edges in the graph, and the red cycle is one contained in `cycles` (which is clearly not a basis cycle). In addition, there are occasional duplicates present in the set.

My question: why does `networkx.cycle_basis` display this behaviour? Is this expected and is my understanding of the cycle basis wrong, or is the output wrong? And is there any way to remove these non-basis cycles?

Comment: Can you explain why the red cycle cannot be a basis cycle?  I believe the definition of a basis here is that any other cycle can be written as a sum of cycles in the basis, and "minimal" means that the basis has a few cycles in it as possible, rather than that the cycles in the basis are as small as possible.

Comment: @Joel The red cycle contains 6 black cycles: 1 pentagon (top left), 1 heptagon (middle), and 4 triangles (bottom right). The red cycle can be constructed by joining these 6 black cycles. Or am I seeing this the wrong way?

Comment: I think what @Joel, ever the diplomat, is trying to say is that the cycle may be a perfectly valid example of a cycle in a cycle basis, and your intuition for a cycle basis is incorrect. A cycle basis is a list of cycles from which all other cycles can be reconstructed. There is absolutely no guarantee that the basis cycles will be small.

Comment: Finding the "holes" in a graph is actually pretty non-trivial. Another user and I have discussed one approach / heuristic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633840/detect-rings-circuits-of-connected-voxels).

Comment: Actually, since your graph is planar, it might be a lot easier than in the example I linked above. So take my previous comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen - And I was editing my comment, so an earlier version suggested it couldn't be written as a sum, but then I saw in the documentation that the summation was "exclusive or".  So MPA was likely responding to my incorrect comment version.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Thanks for your comments. Does the intersection of two cycles in the cycle basis count as a valid way to construct non-basis cycles? So if I have two large basis cycles, I could obtain smaller cycles by taking their intersection?

Comment: @ Joel Yes I was replying to your original comment. What does "exclusive or" imply?

Comment: "exclusive or" means that when we "add" two cycles `A` and `B`, we get a new cycle whose edges are those edges in one of `A` or `B`, but not in both.  So the cycle sum you describe doesn't include edges that are in multiple of the smaller cycles.

Comment: A union of two cycles in the cycle basis should contain 2 cycles if they don't share a node or an edge and three (or more) cycles if they do. The symmetric difference between two cycles should give you another cycle.

Comment: Am I correct that the cycles you want to find are those cycles which can't be broken into smaller cycles?

Comment: @PaulBrodersen Apologies, I meant intersection, not union

Comment: @Joel Correct, I want the smallest possible ("elementary") polygons in the graph

Comment: @MPA The intersection between two basis cycles is not guaranteed to give you another cycle. I think it might even be guaranteed to not give a cycle. The symmetric difference is the union - intersection, which is what you need to construct the other cycles from the basis.

Comment: I am not sure that I would use the cycle basis as my starting point. Too many combinations to try. I would do the following: For each node, 1) determine its neighbours, 2) induce a subgraph with all nodes except that node, 3) find the shortest path between all combinations of neighbours, 4) exclude paths between two neighbours if they contain a third neighbour, 5) add the original node back to close the paths to make cycles. 6) Determine the set of all cycles discovered in this way.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I have tried to follow your instructions, but I can't wrap my head around it. In 2): should the subgraph be induced for only the neighbours? Or all particle minus 1 node?. In 4): with third neighbour, do you mean a node that is not connected to the original node? It would be most helpful if you could provide a (pseudo-)code snippet or an illustration

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838076/small-cycle-finding-in-a-planar-graph

Comment: Regarding 2): all particles minus 1 node; regarding 4): nope, I mean another neighbour from the set of neighbours that we detemined in 1). If you post or link to some example data, I will try to make an implementation tonight or tomorrow (pretty busy atm, sorry).